# Programmatic access to HTTP traffic after CLI call to page (via wget, or urllib2, etc.)

Tags: javascript, python, ruby, firebug, urllib2

Maybe an odd question, but I'm looking to capture the same data you find in Firebug's [*Net* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel) after loading a page (e.g. all the subsequent HTTP calls to resources needed to fully load the page). However, I want to get that data in an automated way, rather than via Firefox / Firebug.

Say I have 100 URL's I want to loop through and for each one grab the many HTTP requests required for each of those pages - all that same data you see in Firebug's *Net* panel.

Any thoughts?

Just to add some detail to the accepted solution below, PhantomJS works for this described use case. One of the examples on the Quick Start page, in fact, does the trick:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.onResourceRequested = function(request) {
  console.log('Request ' + JSON.stringify(request, undefined, 4));
};
page.onResourceReceived = function(response) {
  console.log('Receive ' + JSON.stringify(response, undefined, 4));
};
page.open(url);
```

the onResourceReceived callback returns a JSON object for each resource; one of the contained elements is "url". A simple grep for that, or other way to isolate it as you see fit, and you can accomplish what I describe above.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing this? Depending what it is, there might be an easier way than what you're asking.

Comment: I have a large number of pages with ad content that is served dynamically from a variety of sources outside of my control, but I procedurally whitelist the domains that are allowed to serve content to my pages. I don't do that in real time, of course, so this is my attempt to monitor by loading pages programmatically and comparing the domains of all http calls to my list of known acceptable domains. Currently I have someone manually doing that with Firebug but it's a huge time suck and not an efficient use of resources.

Comment: Automatically whitelisting new domains serving ads may be a risk if the ad provider is not 100% trustworthy.

Comment: Whitelisting is manual - after a new agreement is signed, I have someone modify the list. The purpose of what I'm doing here is to monitor whether or not those agreements are being adhered to. For example, just because a third party ad server agrees to only serve content from xyz.com doesn't mean that's what they will actually do. I need to validate that third parties are adhering to our agreements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a headless web browser if you want to see all the extra requests made by a particular page (CSS, JS, AJAX calls, etc.). [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/network-monitoring.html) is a good choice.

Comment: Thanks - I spent a few minutes reading about PhantomJS and I think this might be the solution; either by itself, or in combination with some python code that calls PhantomJS. I'll mark this as correct once I confirm. Thanks!

Comment: This did the trick. See added detail above in my original post. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Selenium IDE](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/) to parse the page and check for the URLs delivering the advert content. To do so you'll need to [record what you do manually](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#building-test-cases) to create a script you can then run automatically.

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion. I'm not a fan of solutions that require recording of manual interaction with a GUI. I much prefer command line and code, so I'm looking into the PhantomJS solution proposed below.